# ASP.NET Core - How do I get my status code from my C# class to my TypeScript Client App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

I have this controller called ProjectDecommissionRequestController.

And I have this TypeScript client app which basically prints a certain string according to the status code (for e.g gives a generic error in case of status code 500).

```
const response = await fetch(`api/projectdecommissionrequest`, {
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    headers: new Headers({
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }),
    method: "POST",
});
console.log(response.status);
```

My controller calls another class which performs this check and throws an error -

```
 if (!repoUrlFormatMatch.Success)            
                throw new FormatException($"The repositoryUri '{repositoryUri}' did not conform to the expected format for an Azure Devops Git repository.");
```

I want to set the status code for this exception to be something other than 500 so that I can write a more specific error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Then catch the exception?

Comment: the statue codes have their own meanings, 500 error means serverside error, I think you need to catch the detailed exception message instead of modify the statuecode

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StatusCode` method:

```
        public ActionResult MyMethodWithStatusCode(int code)
        {
            return StatusCode(code);
        }
```

There are also shortcut methods for commonly used codes:
[BadRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
[NotFound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-6.0) etc.